How to produce code which treats gmail and googlemail as synonymous as Google itself does?
I am managing a group of email addresses based on entries in a spreadsheet.  The list of email addresses is provided by users.  In one circumstance I have a user with an email address  'abc@gmail.com.  However when I download the list of emails:
group = AdminDirectory.Members.list('player@blowzonetavistock.co.uk').members.email; 

it returns 'abc@googlemail.com'.  The code currently decides therefore that 'abc@gmail.com' is a new member and tries to add them using:
AdminDirectory.Member.Insert('abc.gmail.com, GROUP_EMAIL);

which fails because the 'user already exists'.
My question therefore is how have others dealt with this situation - is there a standard method or simply catch the error and try again?
I've tried to create a reproducible code, but it relies on access to an existing domain and spreadsheet, neither of which I'm able to share anonymously (if there is a way, please let me know).  The code would look like this:

function InsertNewUser() {
  var page;
  var rqdUsers=[];
  var usersEmail=[];
  var testSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Required Users");

  page = AdminDirectory.Members.list('test@dummydomain.co.uk').members;
  usersEmail=page.map((user)=>user.email); //'usersEmail[0]' then has the value abc@googlemail.com

  rqdUsers.push(testSheet.getRange(1,4).getValue()); //'rqdUsers[0]' then has the value abc@gmail.com
  
  //usersEmail[0] <> rqdUsers[0] and hence is assumed to be a new user
  var member = {
    email: rqdUsers[0], //rqdUsers[0]=abc@gmail.com
    role: "MEMBER"
    };
  AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, 'test@dummydomain.co.uk');  //this line fails because the member already exists
}


Grateful for any assistance.

This doesn't do what you ask but it does replace current domains with appropriate replacements
function replacingDomains() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//Emails
  const sr = 2;//data start row
  const es = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const ds = es.map(e => e.split("@")[1]);
  const xrObj = { "domain8.com": "gmail.com", "domain16.com": "gmail.com" };//Data Entry
  Object.keys(xrObj).forEach(k => {
    idx = -1;
    var from = '';
    do {
      var idx = ds.indexOf(k, from)
      if (~idx) {
        es[idx] = es[idx].toString().replace(ds[idx], xrObj[ds[idx]]);
        from = idx + 1;
      }
    } while (~idx)
  })
  Logger.log(es.join('\n'));
  return es;
}

Sheet1:




A




1
emails


2
name1@domain1.com


3
name2@domain2.com


4
name3@domain3.com


5
name4@domain4.com


6
name5@domain5.com


7
name6@domain6.com


8
name7@domain7.com


9
name8@domain8.com


10
name9@domain9.com


11
name10@domain10.com


12
name11@domain11.com


13
name12@domain12.com


14
name13@domain13.com


15
name14@domain14.com


16
name15@domain15.com


17
name16@domain16.com


18
name17@domain17.com


19
name18@domain18.com


20
name19@domain19.com


21
name20@domain20.com



Execution log
8:46:42 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:46:40 AM  Info    name1@domain1.com
name2@domain2.com
name3@domain3.com
name4@domain4.com
name5@domain5.com
name6@domain6.com
name7@domain7.com
name8@gmail.com
name9@domain9.com
name10@domain10.com
name11@domain11.com
name12@domain12.com
name13@domain13.com
name14@domain14.com
name15@domain15.com
name16@gmail.com
name17@domain17.com
name18@domain18.com
name19@domain19.com
name20@domain20.com
8:46:44 AM  Notice  Execution completed
columnOffset: Integer, The number of columns right from the range's top-left cell; negative values represent columns left from the range's top-left cell., Returns a new range that is offset from this range by the given number of rows and columns (which can be negative). The new range is the same size as the original range. ``` var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; var cell = sheet.getRange("A1"); // newCell references B2 var newCell = cell.offset(1, 1); ```, hint


JavaScript.object
*/


Sorry I guess the other volunteers did not wish to reopen that last question.

No idea why, I'll delete it though as without an answer it adds no value.  Many thanks for your suggestion.  As you say, not precisely what I was looking for - but I've applied the technique and it works a treat.  I've marked it as the answer., many thanks.
